# Typecasted signed int converting like unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting

I have a program which outputs a value, call it `x` which could be of any numerical type. When  I typecast `x` as `(int)x`, for positive numbers it works fine, but for negative numbers it seems to be treated it as unsigned. (Doing a modulo INT_MAX +1).

I use it as an array index, and suddenly I was getting many "out_of_range" errors, so I inserted some printfs and made x an integer, and I got this as my output:

```
Before: 44  After: 44
Before: -60 After: 4294967236
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted (core dumped)
```

with the command:

```
std::cout << "Before: " << 2*total_sites + energy_base << "\tAfter: " << 2*total_sites + (int)energy_base << std::endl;
```

where `energy_base` is the "x" I used in my example.

energy_base itself is defined as a double, but it is generated from a function which (for this example), I have restricted to "integer" values. For context, total_sites *is* an unsigned integer.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just for some clarification, yes I know the values that are negative can't be used for an array index, that's an error in my implementation, and one which I'm sorting through now. I posted this because it was a weird error and I didn't understand why it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unsigned + signed, unsigned wins. `(int) energy_base` is converted to an unsigned int for the addition with `2*total_sites`.

Comment: Can you link me to the documentation for this? I can't seem to find that anywhere.

Comment: @NictraSavios [Here you go.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) It's worded a bit confusingly, IMO, but it's there.